# Correct record h1...h6 in sass

Tags: css, sass

I currently learning sass and I want to rewrite my css into sass for learning. I wonder how to save h1 ... h6 in sass. I doing it well?

Is this the correct record in sass?

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Aleo", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color:#000; 
}

h2 {
  @extend h1;
  font-size: 44px;
}

h3 {
  @extend h1;
  font-size: 22px;
}

h4 {
  @extend h1;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#9b9578; 
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h5 {
  @extend h1;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Thank you for all the advice!

Comment: did you test it? the test will tell if it's right or not

Comment: yes it works, but is it the best possible sass record?

Comment: you cannot have a yes/no answer for *is it the best*? there is different ways that works and it's up to you to select the one you think is the *best* for your case

Answer (score 1):

You can use "mixin" and "include" event.

```
  <!-- Set your wants -->
    @mixin anything{
      font-family: "Aleo", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color:#000; 
    }

<!-- and assign to your tag. -->
  h2{
      @include anything;
      font-size: 44px;
    }
```

I think this is correct way to your looking for.